# Extens Boundary in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, openstreetmap

I have put OpenStreetMap service in QGIS and I want to limit the area of zooming in and out. I want to let users to be focused just in one city and I don't want to permit them to pan all over the world (in the base map).

Can you provide me any link to see a Python example?

Comment: you need use python for this.

Comment: Can you provide me any link to see an example, please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this and use it in a project macro or in a plugin. As you want.

```
#Signal extent change
def extentsChange():
    # Check if new center is inside defaul extent
    if not rect.contains(iface.mapCanvas().center()):
        print("Warning!Leaving the area")
        canvas.zoomToPreviousExtent()
        canvas.refresh()


canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
# default extent
rect = QgsRectangle(-4.32802184521001454,40.22504218577429214, -3.0326476391694408,40.58909204729133791)
canvas.setExtent(rect)
canvas.refresh()
# Connect signal
iface.mapCanvas().extentsChanged.connect(extentsChange)
```